# Most efficient way to change endian-ness of a string?

Tags: c

I have a binary string of 64 characters
(1000000011000100101000101110011010010001110101011011001111110111) 
and I would like to change the endian-ness of this binary string based on a variable called bits.

For example, if I have a string of 64 characters:

if bits = 8, each 8 bits are reversed and the program would print out

8-1, 16-9, 24-17, 32-25

if bits = 16, each 8 bits are reversed and the positions of the first byte and second byte are swapped

16-9, 8-1, 32-25, 24-17, 48-41, 40-33, 64-57, 56-49

if bits =32, each 8 bits are reversed and the fourth byte is outputted first, then the 3rd, 2nd, 1st, followed by the 8th, 7th, 6th, 5th

32-25, 24-17, 16-9, 8-1, 64-57, 56-49, 48-41, 40-33

and if bits = 64, the entire string is reversed

64-57, 49-56, etc

All I have is a string reverse function, and I'm not sure how I would go about from here. Any help would be appreciated!

```
char *strrev(char *str){
  if (!str || ! *str) return str;
  char ch;
  int i = strlen(str) - 1, j = 0;
  while (i > j){
    ch = str[i];
    str[i]=str[j];
    str[j]=ch;
    i--;
    j++;
  }
  return str;
}
```

Comment: The first part of your question sounds like theoretical computer science, the second part sounds like you want to do this in C. Which of them is it?

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want to do? Typically endianess only swaps byte  order. (It can sometimes refer to bit order, but it is uncommon)

Comment: @BerndElkemann I want to do this in C! Sorry for the lack of clarification. Visibleman, Yep, this is what I'm attempting to do.

Comment: Double check your examples. Some of the ranges overlap.

Comment: Ok. What does "binary string" mean then?: Binary bytes and you want to reverse their bits?. Or do you mean a C-string containing '0' and '1' which are only representations of bits?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is it for a homework?

Comment: @BerndElkemann the second option! It's simply a string of 64 binary bits

Comment: @n.m. Yes, it's for a homework. I've written a lot of pseudocode and a lot of code involving memcpy and creating temporary arrays in a for loop, but I couldn't get the code to work properly. Instead of printing 0123456789, it would print 9876543210

Comment: Ok, the second option. That is normally not called binary bits. If you are working on a string or array containing '0' and '1' then that is algorithmically the same as working on an array of 'A' and 'B'.

Comment: @BerndElkemann I'm sorry! I'm very new to C and working with binary and hex representation, so I apologize if I accidentally mislabel any terms

Comment: No problem, that is normal. Continued on the comments of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your examples you want:

```
bits = 8:
    8-1, 16-9, 24-17, 32-25
bits = 16:
    16-1, 32-17
bits = 32:
    32-1, 64-33
bits = 64:
    64-1
```

This looks like you'll need two loops. The outer loop for each group of bits and the inner loop to reverse them:

```
void swap(char *str, int i, int j) {
    char tmp = str[i];
    str[i] = str[j];
    str[j] = tmp;
}

char *transform(char *str, int bits) {
    int n = strlen(str);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i += bits) {
        for (int j = 0; j < bits / 2; j++) {
            swap(str, i + j, i + bits - 1 - j);
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: I should have thought about using two functions, I was too wrapped up in the idea of using one function and a nested for loop to solve the problem. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Sure. I haven't tested this or even compiled it so it may need a little work.

Comment: Also I'm not convinced transforming a string like this is what you're really trying to do but it's what you were asking.

Comment: Transforming the string is perfectly fine! Thanks for the help, even if it doesn't compile / work the idea is helpful.

Comment: I did use a nested for loop. I just extracted the `swap()` function to make it a little more readable.

Comment: Shouldn’t i start at 0, not bits?

Comment: @Jeff According to our comments above, this *is* what the OP meant. But one little thing: Your answer has the same confusion: "... group of bits...". We are not working on bits here but on characters (that coincidentally contain '0' and '1').

Comment: @randomir absolutely correct. I started writing this to create a new string and didn't update the loop when I changed it to do it in place.